# User Management group is not listed in target Capabilities on Xcode 14.0.1 and 14 RC 1

Tags: xcode, apple-tv, xcode14

Per this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110384
around 2:58 mark there should be an ability to add "Run as current user"
capability. But User Management is not on the capabilities list.[image]

How could I enable "Run as current user?"

Answer (score 0):

It's in entitlements:

[image]

See more here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvservices/mapping_apple_tv_users_to_app_profiles

To quote:

com.apple.developer.user-management

runs-as-current-user-with-user-independent-keychain

This entitlement value grants your app per-user data storage on tvOS 16 and higher but maintains single-user behavior on tvOS 15 or earlier.